# Persist nested entities NULL value in join column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My class structure is as follows :

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Getter @Setter
public class Product extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected @NotEmpty String name;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    protected Boolean isActive = false;

    @Column(name = "price")
    protected @NotNull Integer price;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    protected ProductDetails productDetails;
}
```

ProductDetails.java

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class ProductDetails extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "description")
    protected String description;

    @Column(name = "cuisines")
    protected String cuisines;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    protected Product product;
}
```

Repositories implements CrudReporitory for product and productDetails both.
And my POST request is :

```
{
    "isActive": true,
    "name": "product4",
    "price": 10,
    "productDetails" : {
        "description": "prod desc 4",
        "cuisines": "south, asian"
    }
}
```

when the above request is sent, 
insert into products (created_at, updated_at, is_active, name, price) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
and insert into product_details (created_at, updated_at, cuisines, description, product_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

gets executed, but product_id is `null` in the case of query 2, which gives me error as `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'product_id' cannot be null`

How can I fix this?

Comment: By setting the ProductDetails.product field to a non-null value. If you tell Hibernate that the product of a ProductDetails is null, it inserts null in the join column mapped to the product field. You don't want a null value in the join column, so you shouldn't leave the product field to null. It's as simple as that.

Comment: that's not the case here, insert into product_details (created_at, updated_at, cuisines, description, product_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), I can see bind parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [south, asian], bind parameter [4] [VARCHAR] - [prod desc 4], but bind param [5] is null. So definitely, ProductDetails.product is a non-null value

Comment: basically, what i'm trying to achieve is, with productService.save(product) method, where product is the JSON object bind with th product class, I'm trying to save the parent Entity `Product` with It's child entity `ProductDetails`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the hint, You are right, productDetails.product was null in my case. I'll post the answer maintaining credits for you. Is it fine for you?